# how to use template Expression Ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm not able to find how to use the expression language on the template. 
I want to show `field: 'name'` in dynamic `template:'<span>{{myDunamicFieldValue}}  </span>'`

here is my code but not working. its output is on the grid  `{{myDunamicFieldValue}}`

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
this.gridColumnDefs = [

      {
        headerName: 'Security Name',
        field: 'name',
        cellStyle: {'text-align': 'left'},
        // width: 250,
        filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
        tooltipField:'name',
        template:'<span>{{myDunamicFieldValue}}  </span>'

      }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all AgGrid ColDef doesn't have any template properties.

And if you want to create a custom header which is described here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#example-header-component

And here is the example of custom Headers https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#example-header-component

Comment: It does have template property, the data is printable on the cell if we write HTML. BTW Thanks for the answer, cellRenderrig s has the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cellRendererSelector` where you can use whole component

```
        {
            headerName: 'Triage Score', field: 'triage.triageScore', width: 150, cellRendererSelector: params => {
                return {
                    component: 'triageScoreCellRenderer',
                    params: {
                        value: params.data.triage.triageScore
                    }
                };

            },
}
```

```
    this.gridOptions = StaticGridOptions.getGridOptions({
        rowClass: 'generalGridStyles',
        components: {
            triageScoreCellRenderer: TriageScoreCellRenderer,
        }})
```

```
class TriageScoreCellRenderer{
    eGui: any;

    init(params: { value: any; }) {
        this.eGui = document.createElement('span');
        this.eGui.innerHTML = `<div class="container"><div class="well-name">${params.value}</div><mat-icon class="ra-icon-analysis-svg mat-icon quick-look">${analysis}</mat-icon></div>`;
        //this.eGui.innerHTML = `<div class="container"><div class="well-name">${params.value}</div></div>`;
    }

    getGui() {
        return this.eGui;
    }
}
```